# Error while trying to generate MySQL Database from EF entity model

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I've been getting an error while trying to generate a MySQL database from my ADO.NET Entity Model. I've setup a connection properly and can connect to it through my Server Explorer. Also the settings in the model seem correct: T4 Code generation strate, Database schema name is correct and the DDL Generation Template is set to SSDLToMySQL.tt. 
Also i cannot seem to map Entities to tables, the dropdown remains empty.

This is the error message:
[image]

I've yet to find a solution and hope someone could help me out :)
I'm new to EF and C#/VS etc.

Cheers,

Comment: which EF and MySQL .net Provider version do you use?

Comment: Both are the latest versions. EF 6.1.1 and MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entity 6.9.5. I have also installed the latest Connector/NET from the MySQL website on my PC. The mysql server is running on ubuntu 12.04 and the mysql version is 5.5.40.

Comment: I've installed a local db running the latest version of mysql to see if this had something to do with it. I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution on the MySQL bug pages.

Here goes:

> Additionally there's a workaround:
>
> On the machine where VS 2013 is installed, VS plugin (1.1.3 GA) and
>   Connector/Net please do the following:
>
> Note: close all VS instances before doing the steps.
>
> On a Windows Explorer window go to this path or wherever the
>   Connector/Net binaries were installed to. By default this is the
>   location:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net
>   6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.5\
>
> Copy the file:
>
> MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
>
> And paste it to this folder
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
>
> If it asks to overwrite it please do so.
>
> In order to copy the file administrator rights are necessary.
>
> Then you can try again to generate the script for your model. It
>   should work fine.
>
> It is important to have the 1.1.3 version of the VS plugin installed
>   since this workaround is for that. The download link is at:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/

Taken from the following page: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71427.